# p:fileUpload - Validate form prior to upload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to be able to trigger validation on my form prior to being allowed to select the files for upload when clicking on the "Choose" button of the fileUpload control in Primefaces. Is this possible? At present the user can click on "Choose" and "Upload" without validation kicking in. This is preventing my document from saving but the attachments are being created. 
I know I could hide the fileUpload control until the form is successfully validated and saved but I would prefer to invoke validation when you click the "Choose" button if possible.
I've tried remoteCommand calls in the onStart but can't seem to get anything to force validation to occur.

Comment: You can use a boolean variable in the "disabled" attribute controlled at the bean and you update the upload component and this variable after the validation.

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for the response. How can I call the validation though when the user clicks on "Choose". I want to do it this way as it provides the user with feedback on what is required before they can upload an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to trigger form validation when `p:fileUpload` Choose button is clicked by combining Java Script and `p:remoteCommand`.

**BASIC CONCEPT**

- intercept Choose button click event, prevent default outcome (opening of file chooser dialog) and run `p:remoteCommand` instead,
- when `p:remoteCommand` completes, and if validation is OK, do not prevent Choose button clicks any more until some data on form input elements is changed again.

**PROOF OF CONCEPT EXAMPLE CODE**

Add this **Java script** in your page

```
    <script>
            var triggerValidation;
            window.onload = function () {
                //initially (after page is loaded) trigger validation on Choose btn click
                triggerValidation = true;
                //define button click listener
                registerChooseBtnClick();
            };

            function registerChooseBtnClick() {
                //var chooseBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-fileupload-choose")[0];
                // or if you define p:upload widgetVar you can use PF function            
                var chooseBtn = PF('fileUploadWidget').chooseButton[0];
                chooseBtn.addEventListener('click', fnRef, false);
            }

            var fnRef = function (event) {
                console.log("Button clicked");
                if (triggerValidation) {
                    //prevent file browser to open
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //trigger validation via p:remoteCommand;
                    submitSelection();
                } else {
                    //File browser will be opened at this point
                }
            };

            function checkIfValidationFailed(xhr, status, args) {
                if (args) {
                    if (args.validationFailed) {
                        console.log("Validation failed");
                        triggerValidation = true;
                    } else {
                        triggerValidation = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            //call each time when form input elements (inputText, ...) change value
            function forceValidation(){
                triggerValidation = true;
            }

        </script>
```

and add **p:remoteCommand**

```
            <p:remoteCommand
                name="submitSelection" process="@form" 
                oncomplete="checkIfValidationFailed(xhr, status, args)" resetValues="true"/>
```

Also here is xhtml page for quick testing

```
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                <!--size is integer variable-->
                <p:inputText id="size" maxlength="3"
                             value="#{yourBean.size}" 
                             required="true" requiredMessage="Size is missing"
                             onchange="forceValidation();"/>

                <p:fileUpload
                    id="upload"
                    widgetVar="fileUploadWidget"
                    fileUploadListener="#{yourBean.onUpload}"
                    multiple="true"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpg|png)$/" />
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:remoteCommand
                name="submitSelection" process="@form" 
                oncomplete="checkIfValidationFailed(xhr, status, args)" resetValues="true"/>
            <p:commandButton
                id="submitBtn" value="Sumbit" process="@form"
                actionListener="#{yourBean.onSubmit()}"/>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution! I have a slight problem with my document having an read/edit mode which prevents the onLoad event from registering the trigger 'Choose' button (the upload control is hidden in read mode) but I'm sure I can work around it.

Comment: I'm glad it might work for you. In that case, you can register trigger after you switch to edit mode and de-register it after you switch to read mode by using chooseBtn.removeEventListener.

Comment: Also if you eventually find this answer useful, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Just one other thing... although 'args' is returning validationFailed it doesn't seem to highlight my required fields so there is no indication to the user that the form has failed. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you should add <p:message for="field_id" /> to every field in order to achive that. You can see example in [PF showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml)

Comment: I do have that, if I save my form all fields that require a value and are empty highlight in red with an "X" next to them. It just isn't happening when the remoteCommand triggers - and I do have process="@form" in the remoteCommand BTW.

Comment: I've added p:message for="size" and update="@form" to my example and tested. It works OK. Sorry but I am not able to help you any more.

Comment: Okay, I've marked your solution as the accepted answer as its obviously something strange going on with my form. Your code has been a big help as I've also been able to disable the save button during the upload operation which was another sticking point. Thanks again for your patients and help.